# Using GSL with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, c

I am trying to use `gsl` in the Raspberry Pi but every time I try to compile I get the following error:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -o interface example.o -pthread -lgsl -lcblas -lm `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:26: all] Error 1
```

I can run the code on my ubuntu machine, so that's why I think it has something to do with the Raspberry Pi. I compiled the library following this [guide](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/11/hello/), except that I am using `gsl-2.6`, I tried installing `libgsl-dev`, but I get the same result. I am trying to run the example [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/usage.html). this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int
main (void)
{
  double x = 5.0;
  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
  printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

and this is the make file that works on my Ubuntu machine:

```
TARGET=interface

# compiler
CC=gcc
# debug
DEBUG=-g
# optimisation
OPT=-O0
# warnings
WARN=-Wall

PTHREAD=-pthread -lgsl -lcblas -lm

CCFLAGS=$(DEBUG) $(OPT) $(WARN) $(PTHREAD) -pipe

GTKLIB=`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

# linker
LD=gcc
LDFLAGS=$(PTHREAD) $(GTKLIB) -export-dynamic

OBJS=    test.o

all: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
    
main.o: src/main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) test.c $(GTKLIB) -o test.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET)
```

Can someone tell me how to get gsl to work?

Comment: What are you doing to resolve the error message?

Comment: I tried installing gsl that is in the respository and I tried linking to the repository I installed. I compiled and installed OpenBlas for Arm6 and still nothing